# Let's get critical: Mar 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Magento Stack Exchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Can't Add Child Block to product_list](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53044/cant-add-child-block-to-product-list)

**Net Score: 20** (Excellent: 20, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Making a purchase without Shipping or Payment. Follow up Invoice with actual shipping costs](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54000/making-a-purchase-without-shipping-or-payment-follow-up-invoice-with-actual-shi)

**Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 13, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Proper use of <slow_backend> for local.xml implementation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54774/proper-use-of-slow-backend-for-local-xml-implementation)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Doubt Regarding Magento Subdomain Creation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57798/doubt-regarding-magento-subdomain-creation)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 15, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Pass session and location between two sub-domains?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54044/pass-session-and-location-between-two-sub-domains)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 14, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Magento 2 backend errors](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55341/magento-2-backend-errors)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Cannot update page template for <review_product_list />](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53494/cannot-update-page-template-for-review-product-list)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 7)

---

- [How to create an admin grid with non auto increment field?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57786/how-to-create-an-admin-grid-with-non-auto-increment-field)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 14, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

- [recently viewed products not showing for guest users](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53058/recently-viewed-products-not-showing-for-guest-users)

**Net Score: -13** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 15)

---

- [Create a custom index with product information](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55057/create-a-custom-index-with-product-information)

**Net Score: -19** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 20)

---

Answer (score 1):

[recently viewed products not showing for guest users](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53058/recently-viewed-products-not-showing-for-guest-users) => Close. Typical case of not checking google. Answer contains a link to here even, that should've come up when posting the question.